# How to change the numbering of \part, \chapter, \section, ... to alphabetical, Roman numbers, etc

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and I want to know how to change the way sections are numbered by default. I use LyX, and there it is relatively simple to change the way an enumeration is numbered, i.e.

```
1 foo
 a bar
   i baz
```

But I want to know if there is a way to do this by default for sections and subsections.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You change section numbering by redefining the commands used to generate each section number. For example, the default `article` class uses something like

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

with similar commands like `\thesubsubsection` and so on -- of course, there's also `\thechapter` (in the `book` and `report` class) and `\thepart`. Commands to typeset numbers include:

- `\arabic` (`1, 2, 3, ...`)
- `\alph` (`a, b, c, ...`)
- `\Alph` (`A, B, C, ...`)
- `\roman` (`i, ii, iii, ...`)
- `\Roman` (`I, II, III, ...`)
- `\fnsymbol` (`∗, †, ‡, §, ¶, ...`)

Comment: If you have any more expertise or examples to add to this answer, I think this would be a good question to serve as a "canonical" question with a widely applicable and extensive answer. I suppose widening the scope of the question a bit would be acceptable as well, even though it's pretty open already. I might come back to this question when I have some time and look into it. The 2.5k views are promising for sure.

Comment: By any chance, do you maybe know, if (or how) can I define my own set of expressions, to be used in similar way as these  typesets above?

Comment: @Kusavil Your best bet is to look at the definition of \fnsymbol in source2e.pdf and go from there.

Comment: Dear @WillRobertson, please, how can I do to add only the first chapter as 0 and the remaining chapters as roman? I tried your answer but it erases the "0" in the first chapter

Comment: @DaniloGregorin That sounds...weird. You probably want to define your own `\RomanMinusOne` command. Better to ask a new question.

Comment: Indeed it is strange, but the book for which I am writing solutions follows this numbering (do Carmo, Geometria Riemanniana, IMPA 2015). Anyway, probably too much work, not worth it just to be like in the book. I will stick to the default numbering. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT: As @Johannes_B pointed out, def is an inappropriate command for general use. The other answer still works.**

---

Another way to do this is to put the command

```
\def\thesection{\alph{section}}
```

in the preamble, where `alph` can be susbtituted for `arabic`, `roman` etc as detailed in the other answer.

See:

http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Numbering#sec-numbering

Comment: Hi and welcome, `def` is a low level command and should be used by experienced users exclusively. It is much better to do `renewcommand` if needed. There is a whole security mechanism behind the scene that `def` does not have.