# How to add a dot after the section number?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, punctuation

I wonder is there any way to change the format of section numbering from 1.1 to 1.1. ? I know this is trivial, but I really need to add one more dot after the section number. Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The KOMA-Script classes have an option for this, if you’re using on of them consider the manual …

Comment: Please see the right side, you can find more. It is one of them: [How to change section numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-section-numbering/3183#3183)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do this simply with the `titlesec` package:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
```

Answer (score 38):

It depends on what you wish precisely. If you want that in all places the section number appears as "1.1.", also in cross references, the question is settled quite easily:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
```

(in this case you would also change chapter numbers, for uniformity).

If you want only the number in the section title to be followed by a period, then you can follow Alan's good suggestion or delve into the internals ([see the FAQ entry for more information](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-seccntfmt)):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
```

This will change the format of all the sectional units also below `\section`. You might prefer the **titlesec** way to get more control on the appearance of the section headings.

Comment: This is more compatible with **microtype** than **titlesc**. Which is to say, I've got a fix for this version, but not if **titlesec** is used.

Comment: Perhaps a show of a redefinition to `\numberline` - for adding dots to the ToC - might help here as well.

Answer (score 17):

If you use [Komascript](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) you may use the option *numbers=endperiod*.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an example corresponding to my above comment!

Comment: After posting my answer I detected your comment - I needed some time to verify my knowledge ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `secdot` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{secdot}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that uses the low-level LaTeX macro called `\@seccntformat`. The main difference to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24444/5001) is that it allows individual control over the formatting of the numbers associated with section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, and subparagraph headers. In the following example, section- and subsection-level numbers get a dot appended, whereas subsubsection-level numbers and beyond do not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\space}       % section-level
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\space} % subsection-level
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % just for this example
\usepackage{cleveref}             % just for this example

\begin{document}
\section{First section} \label{sec:uno}
\subsection{First subsection} \label{sec:uno_uno}

Cross-references to \cref{sec:uno,sec:uno_uno} now look good.
\end{document}
```