# How do I modify the section tag?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to add a dot after the section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/how-to-add-a-dot-after-the-section-number)

Each of my section tags looks like the following:[image]

What I want is punctuation after each section number. I am not sure where the TeX is that generates the section numbers.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: which documentclass?

Comment: Since your question is (in spirit) the same as the question linked in the comment above and since the answers listed there apply to your case as well, I am voting to close this as a duplicate to keep the place tidy.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest is

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
```

Which will put a `.` after all uses of the section counter, including references to sections. If you only want to change the section head (and table of contents?) then it is a bit more involved, and depends on the document class you are using.

If you do the above however you probably need to also redefine

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
```

so you don't get two `..` there.

Comment: I voted to close this question as duplicate. This answer is equivalent to egreg's answer to the linked question but there are other good suggestions there as well.