# How to insert a dot in the section headings?

Tags: sectioning, punctuation

I am using this macro:

```
    \newcommand{\ssection}[1]{\section[1]{\centering #1}}

    \ssection{BACKGROUND}
```

Result, is centered but there are couple of spaces between 1 and B:

> 1  BACKGROUND

The result i am looking for

> 1.BACKGROUND

```
   \newcommand{\ssection}[1]{. \section[1]{\centering #1}}
```

This gives me '1.' two extra spaces then '.BACKGROUND'

Comment: META: how do i put extra spaces here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) -- formatting help can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: have you seen [How to add a dot after the section number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24439)

Comment: just in case you see this comment before it gets closed, can you confirm that the linked question is a duplicate? :)