# Dots after section number in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing my thesis in Lyx and my supervisor has very specific editing requirements. He wants that the chapter number in `ToC` would be followed by dot, but section numbers not.

Here's code from document class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\def\@baseclass{report}
\def\@rodzajpracy{magisterska}
\DeclareOption{licencjacka}{\def\@rodzajpracy{licencjacka}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\@baseclass}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt}{\@baseclass}
\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{\@baseclass}


\renewcommand*\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\enspace}
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\mdseries
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}


\endinput
%%
%% End of file `book.cls'.
```

Working example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{blabla}


\section{blab blab}


\chapter{bleble}


\section{bleb bleb}
\end{document}
```

and this is what I get:
[image]

adding numbers=noenddot in lyx->settings->document class doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the line

```
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
```

from the class code and change the definition of `\l@chapter` as follows:

```
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{##1.\hfil}}%<------ this line added
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\mdseries
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

The trick is to do the redefinition of `\numberline` only locally for chapters.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked without any problems. I'm quite new to LaTeX so I would have never came up with this change.

Comment: @Marta I'd avoid calling `book` that class. But maybe you're forced to because of LyX (a tool that I would never use).

Comment: you are right, I wanted to create my own class with it's own name but I can't get lyx to work with it, so I just decided to replace on of the classes that were available, even though I know it's not the best option at least it works

Comment: @egreg How can we add a dot after section numbers in TOC without using additional package like `tocloft`?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan What's the connection with this answer?

Comment: @egreg I'm just curious to know how to add a dot after section numbers in TOC without using additional packages.

Answer (score 7):

The package `tocloft` and its command `\cftchapaftersnum` provide the possibility to add 'anything' to the chapter number in the toc, i.e. a dot `.` too.

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{babel}

\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{blabla}


\section{blab blab}


\chapter{bleble}


\section{bleb bleb}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution, with [this one too](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24440/101590), is really useful! Thanks!

Comment: This is for sections numbering `\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}%` . Thank you for your useful answer.