# Table of Contents Chapter Numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, chapters, tocloft

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir}
```

In my table of contents

I get the same problem as [Dots after section number in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197977/dots-after-section-number-in-toc) .

My chapter number in the TOC is like:

[image]

I want to include a dot after chapter number in TOC.

I used the second solution of the question above:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}%
```

But it is not working,

I get the error

```
LaTeX Error: \cftchapaftersnum undefined
```

Comment: `memoir` has a similar functionality as `tocloft` (they are written by the same person), thus `tocloft` is never loaded in `memoir`. Please refer to the `memoir` manual to get the `memoir` equivalent name (there are slight naming differences). Plus next time please remember to post a full miunimal example instead of posting sniplets like this

Comment: Note that adding `\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}` to document preamble adds dots to every entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve the problem:

```
\def\cftchapteraftersnum{.}
```

Edit: try with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,leqno,footinclude=true]{memoir} 
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\def\cftchapteraftersnum{.} 
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{blabla} 
\section{blab blab} 
\chapter{bleble} 
\section{bleb bleb} 
\end{document}
```

BTW: `\cftchapteraftersnum` is used in `memoir.cls` for defining `\l@chapapp`.

Comment: And please don't use `\def`, normal users should never use `\def`