# I want to place a dot after the numbers of sections, subsections, and subsubsections

Tags: numbering, titlesec

My goal is as stated in the question title. There are other questions addressing this, but the answers selected, as best I can tell, don't get along with my other existing code, which is summarized below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,titlesec}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newcommand{\periodafter}[1]{#1.}
\newcommand{\presectionskip}{-1\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\postsectionskip}{0.3\baselineskip}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}%% name, level, indent
        {\presectionskip}% % beforeskip
        {\postsectionskip}% % afterskip
        {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}% % style
    \renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
        {subsection}{2}{0mm}
        {\presectionskip}
        {\postsectionskip}
        {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
    \renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection
        {subsubsection}{3}{0mm}
        {\presectionskip}
        {\postsectionskip}
        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

%\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
%\titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection.}{1ex}{\periodafter}
%\titleformat{\subsection}{}{\thesubsection.}{1ex}{\periodafter}
%\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\begin{document}
\section{Good section}\label{sec:refl}
\subsection{Superior subsection}\label{tableworks}
\subsubsection{This, the best of all subsections}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any ideas on how to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24444) works perfectly. Do you have concerns about getting a dot in references as well?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\presectionskip}{-1\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\postsectionskip}{0.3\baselineskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}%% name, level, indent
    {\presectionskip}% % beforeskip
    {\postsectionskip}% % afterskip
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}% % style
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
    {subsection}{2}{0mm}
    {\presectionskip}
    {\postsectionskip}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection
    {subsubsection}{3}{0mm}
    {\presectionskip}
    {\postsectionskip}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \section{Good section}\label{sec:refl}
    \subsection{Superior subsection}\label{tableworks}
    \subsubsection{This, the best of all subsections}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ... thought I'd tried all of those. I definitely tried the first component of the `egreg` answer, but obviously failed to try the second. :/ But thank you so much! What do you mean about references?

Comment: @jdc regarding egregs answer, you will get a dot as well, when you use some `\ref` or similar. Makes sense to have it like this, in your case. But you have to consider that "chapter 1. is showing..." could be a bit difficult to read especially, if the dot is set at the end of a line.

Comment: I thought that was what you meant, but for whatever fortunate reason, that's not happening to me; my document doesn't have excess dots after `\Cref`s. I tried a `\ref` as well to check, and there was no dot.

Comment: @jdc oh sorry, I mixed it up. There will be no period, you are right. If you want one, you have to use one of the other answers. I would recommend `titlesec` for all this stuff.

Comment: I am using `titlesec`, although I don't remember what I'm using it for. That's the danger with understanding as little as I do and adapting advice one finds online, I suppose.