# Can you change the style of the section number but not the subsection

Tags: titlesec

So I'd like to make the section headers be `1. Introduction` for instance but not the subsections `1.1      Subsection`

I've tried these commands here: [How to add a dot after the section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/how-to-add-a-dot-after-the-section-number) but they all add dots to section and subsection titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
```

Comment: this will change it every where even in subsection, references

Comment: sure, it should not be different ...