# Headings change influence the caption formatting (srcreprt)

Tags: sectioning, captions

I had to change the headings (chapter, sections, subsections...) for a journal to get a final point after the last number. Example:

```
1 My First Chapter 
1. My first Chapter
```

Therefore, I added the following stuff to my preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
```

The problem that I have now is, that the captions of the figures and tables, and also the references are not correct anymore because I got the additional point:

```
\caption{Evaluation of the arbitrary temperature profiles on $n$ random points (red)}
```

Will be displayed as:

> Figure 2..2: Evaluation of the arbitrary temperature profiles on n random points (red)

As you can, I got the additional point between the numbers, which comes from the added lines above. Based on the feedback I got, I checked out the following thread: [How to add a dot after the section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/how-to-add-a-dot-after-the-section-number) , which is finally what I am searching for but the commands:

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle.}
```

Is not working within my class (scrreprt}. Doing so, I get the error message:

> Undefined control sequence \section{Latex}

At the moment I do not know how to change this behavior. Any suggestion is warmly welcomed.

By the way, to all supporters and volunteers, you do a really great work.!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What document class are you using?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the hint about the duplicate. I really wanted to avoid that but without searching with the correct keywords, it is not always easy to find the corresponding topic. 

However, I tried it out and figured out that this is not working based on the document class I am using. 

@StefanPinnow, thank your for the kind words. I added the document class to the question.

Comment: The document class sometimes matters with questions like this, that is why we often ask for an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can see what you are trying to do in the context of your actual document.

Comment: @moewe thank you for the comment. I got the answer below (comment on first answer) and keep in mind that the next time I will present some small example that demonstrates the problem (that makes live easier). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal: you changed the way the chapter, section, &c. counters are displayed. Likewise, for cross references, you'd obtain things like ‘We've seen in Chapter 1. that …’ instead of  ‘We've seen in Chapter 1 that …’.
A simple way to obtain a dot *only* in chapter, section, &c. titles, is to load `titlesec`(if compatible with your class) and in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle. }
```

Comment: Dear Bernhard, I checked out your suggestion (like in the link given by Werner) but it is not working. I  changed my question with the new information.

Comment: Yes, koma-script is incompatible with title sec. You can use the document class option `[numbers=\endperiod]` (see table 3.14, p.89 of the english documentation). The default is `[noendperiod]`, and follows the German typographical tradition.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your option was the right one (without the backslash). Great.