# Error: Command \textomicron unavailable in encoding T1

Tags: errors, input-encodings

[image]

Can someone help me with this? I am really new to Latex and this really frustrates me

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=1.91cm, right=1.91cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\babeltags{en = english}
\begin{document}
\title{Δισκόμορφοι Υγροί Κρύσταλλοι}
\author{Θεοδωρίδης Αθανάσιος}
\maketitle
\section*{1. Εισαγωγή}
Η μελέτη των υγρών κρυστάλλων ξεκίνησε το 1888 από τον βοτανολόγο \en{Friedrich Reinitzer} , ο οποίος εξέταζε τις ιδιότητες διαφόρων παραγώγων χοληστερίνης, και παρατήρησε την αλλαγή των ιδιοτήτων τους με την μεταβολή της θερμοκρασίας.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't show screenshots of code. We can't copy & paste them to test the issue.

Comment: sorry i will post the text then

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does `\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}` help? Please include your code as copy-and-paste-able text in your question. An image is not searchable for text and we don't have to re-type its contents.

Comment: Hello! I've tried adding LGR but still the same problem

Comment: `\en` seems to be a switch and not a macro. Try `{\en Friedrich Reinitzer}` and not `\en{Friedrich Reinitzer}`. **Edit** according to the `babel` documentation `\texten{Friedrich Reinitzer}` (with `text`) is preferred.

Comment: Thank you!!! this seems to have fixed this!
Also I tried the \begin{en} \end{en} command and it works too!

Comment: But I would not use the environment form of `\begin{en}...\end{en}` for two words.

Comment: Yes of course since you showed me a better route! Thanks again!

Comment: BTW: I don't think you need `\usepackage{textgreek}` if you type Greek directly and don't use `\textalpha` etc.

Comment: Ideally you'd use `\section{Εισαγωγή}` instead of `\section*{1. Εισαγωγή}`. That way TeX does the counting and numbering of the sections for you. If you want the dot back, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24439/35864

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the `\babeltags` command in the [`babel` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) says (emphasis mine)

> `\babeltags{<tag1>=<language1>, <tag2>=<language2>, ...}`
>
> In multilingual documents with many language switches the commands above
>   can be cumbersome. With this tool shorter names can be defined. It adds nothing really new – it is just syntactical sugar.
>
> It defines `\text<tag1>{<text>}` to be `\foreignlanguage{<language1>}{<text>}`, and `\begin{<tag1>}` to be `\begin{otherlanguage*}{<language1>}`, and so on. *Note `\<tag1>` is also allowed, but remember to set it locally inside a group.*

This means that `\en` acts like a switch and not a macro. You want

```
\texten{Friedrich Reinitzer}
```

or `{\en Friedrich Reinitzer}` instead of `\en{Friedrich Reinitzer}`