# Add dot after chapter title (scrreprt document)

Tags: titles, chapters, scrreprt

I have a problem with the numbers added to the chapters of my document: There is no dot after the number, e. g. "2 Theory" instead of "2. Theory".
I tried adding a dot before the chapter title but then it looks like "2  . Theory".
I also tried `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrreprt}` and `%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}` but both add a dot after every number, even "1.1. Title" where I want "1.1 Title".

My document looks like this:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \graphicspath{{img/}}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{caption}
     \usepackage{textcomp}

    \addtokomafont{section}{\small}
    \addtokomafont{subsection}{\small}
    \addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\small}


\begin{document}
\include{theory}
\include{experiment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446836/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: Please note that your example is not a working example. The include command could be replaced with a simple chapter command.

Comment: @leandriis This works perfectly, thank you again, you are saving my thesis!

Comment: @leandriis: I really should have red the question *in extenso* ;o)

Answer (score 4):

If sections, subsections etc. should not get a dot after the number, use option `numbers=noenddot`. One possibility to add the dot after chapter number is

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\chapterformat{\autodot}{.}{}{\PatchFailed}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithdot
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand*\entrynumberwithdot[1]{\def\autodot{.}#1}
```

Example (with additional remarks):

```latex
\documentclass[
  %a4paper,11pt,% default
  numbers=noenddot% default value: autoenddot
]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}% <- added
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% it is suggested to use package scrlayer-scrheadings
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}% maybe you can use KOMA-Script commands?
\usepackage{textcomp}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\small
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\chapterformat{\autodot}{.}{}{\PatchFailed}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithdot
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand*\entrynumberwithdot[1]{\def\autodot{.}#1}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the MWE

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the koma option

`numbers=enddot`

so the first line will be

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,numbers=enddot]{scrreprt}
```

Edit:

This will set points also after section numbers.

You may want to go with: [Remove last dot in title numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202928/remove-last-dot-in-title-numbering)

This is a solution specifically for KOMA-Script

Comment: As the OP already mentioned in her question, this will also add a period after the section number which seems to be undesired. " I also tried `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrreprt}`[...]  add a dot after every number, even "1.1. Title" where I want "1.1 Title". "

Answer (score 0):

This should work in every `documentclass` and it is based on my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\graphicspath{{img/}}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{caption}
     \usepackage{textcomp}

    \addtokomafont{section}{\small}
    \addtokomafont{subsection}{\small}
    \addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\small}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{%
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.}%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter*{#2}%
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\oldchapter*{#1}%
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}%
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldchapter{#1}%
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in the MWE
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Adding in order to be able to help people with other document classes or even for the OP's request if he would like to be able to change `documentclass` later.

Comment: Then chapters in appendix also get arabic numbers. Additionally the dot is in references, if you use `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}` for a chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @esdd ... You are right ... Could take care of the first easily ... but not of the second (not so easy but with some effort -as far as I can think right now- ...) Anyway ... thanks! Useful comment ... and more useful answer!