# Unnecessary dots in theorems and figure numbers

Tags: numbering, amsthm

I know, that it is possible to add dot after the chapter / section / subsection number. But if I use

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
```

(as in this solution: [How to add a dot after the section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/how-to-add-a-dot-after-the-section-number)), then I have too many dots in the case of number of figure / theorem etc. For example, if I apply

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}

\newtheorem{defin}{Def.}[chapter]
\newtheorem{tw}[defin]{Th.}

\begin{document}

\chapter{New chapter}

\begin{defin}
Some definition
\end{defin}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Some algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[hptb]
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\section{New section}

\begin{defin}
Some definition
\end{defin}


\end{document}
```

then I have
[image]

How could I remove the unnecessary dots in **1..1** and similar numbers? Thank you in advance for your answer.
**Edit:** I have realized, that my question can be put in other way. Is this possible to add dots, but only: 1. in the case of titles of chapters / sections etc. 2. and in the case of table of contents, but not for other references?

Comment: You should really apply the period (dot) to the *target* counter, e.g., `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that instead of this code

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
```

I should use

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle .\quad}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
```

But I'm still looking for the answer in the case of chapters.

Comment: Please don't answer your question. Instead, Edit your question.

Comment: @ferahfeza Self-answers are fine. In this case, though, I’d agree that an edit is better. This is only a partial answer, and the author still hopes for a more complete one,  but it makes the question appear to have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Patch `\@seccntformat`, `\floatc@ruled`  and `\@makechapterhead` to add the period.

Also add `\@` both in `\@seccntformat` and in the `\newtheorem` with `Def.` or the period would produce extended end-of-sentence space.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\@\quad}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\thechapter.}{}{}
\patchcmd{\floatc@ruled}{#1}{#1.\@}{}{}
\makeatother


\newtheorem{defin}{Def.\@}[chapter]
\newtheorem{tw}[defin]{Th.}

\begin{document}

\chapter{New chapter}

\begin{defin}
Some definition
\end{defin}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Some algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[hptb]
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\section{New section}

\begin{defin}
Some definition
\end{defin}

\end{document}
```

[image]