# How to remove dot of section in \ref{}?

Tags: cross-referencing, punctuation

I renewed my section with dot and I want to get a number without dot when I use \ref{}. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand\thesection{\normalsize{\arabic{section}.}}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} \label{s-1}
I want to print just a number of Section \ref{s-1} without dot.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Rather not renew that command and use one of these suggestions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/how-to-add-a-dot-after-the-section-number

Comment: Another reason not to renew `\thesection` to have the dot is that the default `\thesubsection` would then have two dots: "Subsection 1..1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require any external LaTeX packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%% Do _not_ do this:
%\renewcommand\thesection{\normalsize{\arabic{section}.}}

%% Instead, do this:
% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\space} % section-level
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} \label{s-1}
I can cross-reference the number of Section \ref{s-1} without a trailing dot.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than change the meaning of `\thesection`, I leave it as is, without the dot, and change the manner that the section heading is output, by specifying a suffix to be appended to `\thesection`, for example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\renewcommand\thesection{\normalsize{\arabic{section}.}}
\makeatletter
%% SECTIONING \hskip'S BEFORE SECTIONING TITLES
\def\sectionkern      {1em}
\def\subsectionkern   {1em}
\def\subsubsectionkern{1em}
\def\paragraphkern    {1em}
%% SUFFIX ADDED TO \the SECTIONING MACROS
\def\sectionsuffix      {.}
\def\subsectionsuffix   {}
\def\subsubsectionsuffix{}
\def\paragraphsuffix    {}
%% SECTIONING LABEL: \the[section]\[section]suffix\hskip\[section]kern
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\normalsize\csname the#1\endcsname%
  \csname#1suffix\endcsname\hskip\csname#1kern\endcsname\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} \label{s-1}
I want to print just a number of Section \ref{s-1} without dot.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a very simple solution with `titlesec`, which adds a dot for all section levels, and doesn't modify  `\thesection` &  al.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle. }

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} \label{s-1}
I want to print just a number of Section \ref{s-1} without dot.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This approach prints subsection numbers as, for example, `1.1.`, with a trailing dot.  Is that a common format?

Comment: I think I've already seen it. Whether it's common, I couldn't say. Other that, one would have to use the advanced interface of titlesec to enable the final dot for sections only.