# Suppress the 'dot' after section numbers when using \ref{[label]}

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to have sections numbers as I., II., and subsections as A., B., etc:

I.

II.
A.
B.

But when I refer to those sections/subsections with \ref{[label]} in the text, I don't want the dot after the section number. I want: 'In s.I', and not 'In section I.' .

How do I do this?
Thank you.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4,twoside,british,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
```

Comment: Move the `.` from definitions of `\the(sub)section` into corresponding title format, e.g., `\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\thesection.}{1em}{}` (note the `.` right after `\thesection`).

Comment: @muzimuzhi Thank you!

Comment: (actually check out the linked duplicate within that question, seems to contain simpler answers) Does this answer your question? [How to remove dot of section in \ref{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566945/how-to-remove-dot-of-section-in-ref)