# Adjust title spacing for long title

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I want to adjust title margins for two lines length titles. For example, is like below. How can I adjust.
Thank you for your understanding I don't know how can I explain my problem.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
```

[image: What I Want]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve the desired output with the machinery of the `titlesec` package. Here's a solution that employs the `sectsty` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{newtxtext} % optional (Times Roman clone text font)

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\nohang\noindent}
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24444/5001:
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{subsection}{3}
\stepcounter{subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Outage probability for cooperative transmission using DF method under co-channel interference effect}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I use titlesec package

Comment: @Diagram - Thanks. Is there something keeping you from switching from a `titlesec`-based solution to the `sectsty`-based solution shown above?

Comment: I have a thesis template overleaf document. I don't know how can I adapt my document to sectsty package.

Comment: @Diagram - I guess you could (a) edit the template file to comment out the instruction that loads the `titlesec` package and (b) add the 6 instruction lines -- 5 lines without the comment line `% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24444/5001:` -- shown above to the preamble of your document.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\parbox{\textwidth}}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{#1}[]
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}\setcounter{subsection}{3}\setcounter{subsubsection}{1}
\subsubsection{Outage probability for cooperative transmission using DF method under co-channel interference effect}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously not perfect, but a start, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `block` format.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Outage probability for cooperative transmission using 
  DF method under co-channel interference effect}
\subsection{Outage probability for cooperative transmission using
  DF method under co-channel interference effect}
\subsubsection{Outage probability for cooperative transmission using
  DF method under co-channel interference effect}

\end{document}
```

[image]