# How to left align a TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

I am currently formatting a TOC. I am getting rid of the number of the chapters only in the TOC, as can be seen in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % To customise TOC.

% TOC SETTINGS

\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\listoftoc*{toc}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Fancy title 1}

\section{Section title 1}

\section{Section title 2}

\end{document}
```

The MWE produces the following output:
[image]

I want to the numbers of the sections to be aligned with the chapter; that is, on the red line of the next picture:
[image]

**Can anybody help me please achieve that?**

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix the use of [Koma-script classes](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) and [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), since the class already provides features to deal with ToC-related adjustments.

Specifically, you can change the `default` style associated with `section`s and remove the `indent`:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{default}{section}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently loading `tocloft` because I use `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}` and similar commands to get a `.` before each number in the TOC. How can I achieve that without `tocloft`?

Comment: you should be able to control this with the `numbers=endperiod` options (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24448/12332)