# enumeration of sections in a chapter

Tags: sectioning, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change section numbering to alphabetical, Roman numbers, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-section-numbering-to-alphabetical-roman-numbers-etc)

I am using the `fancyhdr` package to work with chapters. But I don't want to have the number of the chapter included in the section numbering. For example, I don't want to have

> chapter 1
>
> 1.1 Introduction.
>
> 1.2 Conclusion.

The preamble concerning the `fancyhdr` package is

```
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
 \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
 \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-section-numbering-to-alphabetical-roman-numbers-etc help you?

Comment: Not sure how the linked post helped you, but you can remove the chapter number from the section numbering via `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Without any modifications to the [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) or [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) document classes (which support `\chapter`), the section printing mechanism is essentially given by

```
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

This includes the chapter-level numbering - `\thechapter` (and a period `.`) - as part of the section-level numbering. To remove this hierarchy, add

```
\renewcommand \thesection {\arabic{section}}
```

to your document preamble.