# In LyX, how to change section headings from Arabic to Roman

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx, roman-numerals

I'm relatively new to LyX. I'm writing an article and would need to change the numbering of sections from Arabic to Roman. Would anyone know how to do this? (e.g. by means of ERT?)

Also, the subsections, I would need to change, to alphabetical (without reference to the section, so, e.g. section "A" rather than section "2.A").

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the LaTeX part of this can be found in [How to change the numbering of \part, \chapter, \section, ... to alphabetical, Roman numbers, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-the-numbering-of-part-chapter-section-to-alphabetical-r?rq=1). You need to such commands to the preamble, by going to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble.

To get the result you ask for, add

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
```

to the preamble.

Comment: Hi Torbjørn T. Where have you been all my life) :) You've solved all the issues I've been struggling with for quite some time... Thanks!

Comment: @tompv Glad I could help. If you like, you could consider accepting my answers by clicking the checkmark on the left. This marks the question as solved (and awards some points to both of us).