# How can I define my own sequence of symbols for a new counter style?

Tags: counters

I know I can change a counter style as this:

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
```

(The above command will make chapter numbers be written in upper case roman numerals)

However, according to [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters) and an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-the-numbering-of-part-chapter-section-to-alphabetical-r), I can only choose among arabic, roman, greek and footnote symbols:

- `\arabic` 1, 2, 3 ...
- `\alph` a, b, c ...
- `\Alph` A, B, C ...
- `\roman` i, ii, iii ...
- `\Roman` I, II, III ...
- `\fnsymbol` Aimed at footnotes; prints a sequence of symbols.

Is there a way I can define my own symbol sequence for a counter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can easily adapt the definition of `\alph` which is defined like this in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\alph#1{\expandafter\@alph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
```

So here is a MWE for a custom sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\mysequence#1{\expandafter\@mysequence\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@mysequence#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or AAA\or BBB\or CCC\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thesection{\mysequence{section}}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
%\section{Section} % --> LaTeX Error: Counter too large
\end{document}
```

Be aware, that this implementation stops working if the counter value is too high (in my example 4). So make sure you define enough symbols.