# Problematic Sections numbering in Lyx - RTL

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, lyx, languages, hebrew

In my University there is a defined format for thesis writing, and I ran into a problem every I try to compile the given file. The format available in this **[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3qnsDa7ZucCQ0VFUzVNSmNZZ1k/view)**, and the head file (which I need to compile) is *'thesis_head'*.

As it can be seen in the following image, The chapters numbers appear to be mirrored:

[image]

I tried to add anything that I could find on the web to solve this problem, but nothing helped. It's important to say that I'm using RTL language (Hebrew) in one chapter of the file. Can someone help?

The preamble of the main file is:

```
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\def \hebrewFont{Ezra SIL}


\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{\hebrewFont}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{\hebrewFont}
\setmonofont{\hebrewFont}
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\LRE{#1}}}
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip)}}


\global\long\def\vec#1{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

Appriciate your help, Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like it's going subsection.section.chapter. Have you tried `\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}` and `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}`? Modified from this suggestion here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3183/51373?

Comment: Tried it. Wasn't work. The Hebrew numbering is fine, but the English chapters still mirrored :( @Alwin