# How can I change format of number of section and subsection in the list of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

Please consider the following codes:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\end{document}
```

I want to appear statements "1-1-" and "1-1-1-" instead of "1.1" and "1.1.1" in the list of contents. Can you help?

Comment: This is a standard question here: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter-\arabic{section}}`

Comment: See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-the-numbering-of-part-chapter-section-to-alphabetical-r