# I want to add a dot after sections and subsections numbers

Tags: section-titles

I want to add a dot after sections and subsections numbers, even in the **table of contents** and **cross-references**. With `\sectiondot{subsection}` of `secdot` package we don't get the final dot in **table of contents** and **cross-references.**

I have tried by redefining the following commands:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
```

But the result in the table of contents is the following:
[image]

That is, the **subsections** appear numbered as if they were **subsubsections**.

And the **subsections headings** shows as follows:
[image]

**EDIT 1 _______________________________________________________________**

With this **code of Dr. Manuel Kuehner**,

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
```

the result is correct in the **table of contents** but in the **headings of sections and subsections** we get this:

[image]

**EDIT 2 _______________________________________________________________**

Furthermore, I wish the chapter numbers do not end by a dot, as they will go inside a box, as it is shown in this image:

[image]

**EDIT 3 _______________________________________________________________**

Finally, this is the **code that has worked for me**:

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
```

The conflict was caused by definitions that I had used in another book by which I got the point to the right of the number of titles, but not in the TOC (the points that I have marked here with ** strong. text ** to highlight them):

```
% Section style definition
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalsize \bfseries}
{\color{black} \S \thesection **strong . text**}
{1ex}{\color{black}}[\qquad]

% Subsection style definition
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalsize \bfseries}
{\color{black} \S \thesubsection **.**}
{1ex}{\color{black}}[\qquad]
```

When trying to get the dot after the section number, etc., in the TOC, having forgotten the above definitions, I got these strange results.

I apologize to all of you who have so generously given some of your precious time trying to help me. With your collaboration, seeing that you got correct results and I did not, I was forced to carefully review my code (quite cumbersome) and thus get to discover the cause of the error. By deleting the dots in `\thesection` **strong . text** and `\thesubsection **.**`, obviously, the problem disappeared.

Now it only remains to solve **how to put the dot after chapter numbers in the TOC** (see screenshot below):

[image]

**EDIT 4 _______________________________________________________________**

Simplifying the statement, the problem to be solved is as follows: add a dot to the right of all **part**, **chapter**, **section** and **subsection** **numbers**, both in headings (except for chapters, which must go without a period in headings, but not in TOC) and in TOC.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the used **document class**.

Comment: The document class is book.

Comment: I give up now :). I asked two times nicely that you provide a mwe and not just code fragments. This is a reasonable request that is beneficial for yourself and also for the people to try to help you. And yes, it needs some effort on your end to provide a useful mwe.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good to me (I did not test it thoroughly because I am about to leave my apartment). Even if this does not solve your problem, you can use the code as an example of how to provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) on this site.

```
\documentclass{book}

% For the \blinddocument command.
\usepackage{blindtext}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Chapter number without dot (untested):

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dr. Manuel Kuehner; the result in the TABLE OF CONTENTS is what I want to get, but the headings of sections and subsections add a duplicated dot at the end (see an image of the result in EDIT 1).

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarezLobo Please check my added screenshot, as you can see, it looks correct. I suggest that you take my code as a start and provide a complete (compilable) code in your question. With the fragmented information that you currently provide, it is (for me) impossible to guess what your actual problem is. You can have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you very much, again, Dr. Manuel Kuehner. You can see the final solution and the cause of the errors in may EDIT 3.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to add the dot after the number, but *only* in the table of contents.

In this instance, the best approach would be to modify how things are printed in the table of contents. If you look in your `.toc` file, you'll likely see something like:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {4}Defining new commands and environments}{79}{}%
```

The `\numberline` command is what's responsible for printing the number. It reserves a certain amount of space and puts the number inside of it. What we'll do is save the definition of `\numberline` using `\let`:

```
\let\OldNumberline=\numberline
```

Then we can redefine `\numberline` to call the old definition but with a dot after the argument:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\numberline}{ m }{% ❶
   \OldNumberline{#1.}%
}
```

If you have an old LaTeX distribution (before October 2020), you should replace the line marked ❶ with

```
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
```

Also, this assumes that you're using a document class which doesn't deviate significantly from the way the standard LaTeX classes handle the table of contents. Looking at the `.toc` file will help verify that this approach will work.

Comment: Thank you very much, Don Hosek. One last question: how to modify only chapter numbers, adding the dot to the right?