# How to convert the sections no. from (I, II, ...) into number (1., 2., ...)

Tags: sectioning

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{slashbox}
%\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,dsfont,nicefrac}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=0
\allowdisplaybreaks

\newcommand{\nn}{{\mathcal N}}
\newcommand{\cc}{{\mathcal C}}
\newcommand{\cl}{{\mathcal L}}
\newcommand{\kk}{{\mathcal K}}
\newcommand{\rr}{{\mathcal R}}
\newcommand{\xx}{{\mathcal X}}
\newcommand{\ii}{{\mathcal I}}
\newcommand{\scrl}{{\mathscr L}}
\newcommand{\VC}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\bsell}{\boldsymbol\ell}
\newcommand{\bsk}{\boldsymbol \kappa}
\newcommand{\bsr}{\boldsymbol r}
\newcommand{\bsal}{\boldsymbol\alpha}
\newcommand{\bsbe}{{\boldsymbol \beta}} 
\newcommand{\R}{\mathds{R}}
\newcommand{\rect}{\,{\rm rect}}
\newcommand{\erfc}{\,{\rm erfc}}
\newcommand{\snr}{\,{\rm SNR}}
\newcommand{\defas}{\buildrel \rm def \over =}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
    \colorbox{yellow!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUCTION\label{I}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the numbering of \part, \chapter, \section, ... to alphabetical, Roman numbers, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/how-to-change-the-numbering-of-part-chapter-section-to-alphabetical-r). Also, your MWE did not work for me because I don't have slashbox, but I am assuming it does not affect the answer given in the question I linked here.

Comment: The standard `article` class uses arabic numbering for its sections.  If you're using IEEE because you're planning on submitting an article, don't change how they set things up.  (Also, don't label things with `I` - if you change the order, that makes your labeling wrong (less of an issue for an introduction, but what if you add `\section{Preface}`?).)